# Can't Remove Downloaded Music From Ipod Touch

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, music

Ever since the apple music update I've been unable to add or remove music from my ipod touch 5 via itunes on my computer. Everywhere I've looked says you go to the ipod icon, go into summary and click "manually manage music and videos" but mine only shows the option to "manually manage videos". I would like to be able to delete all of the music off of my ipod and start fresh because it somehow duplicated my entire playlist and is taking up double the amount of space it should. 
Currently the only way I've found to do that is to individually go through and delete each of the 2000 songs twice, and that's a huge waste of time, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Having the same song in 2 playlists does not double the amount of data stored, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the duplicate playlist from the iPod, but the actually music files shouldn't be duplicated anyway. Nevertheless, if you would like to delete all stored music (not including what's in the cloud), you can (on your iPod) navigate to Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage (For Device Storage, not iCloud) > Music > Edit and tap delete next to "All Songs".